# Handling Dynamic List/dropdowns in Appium(Android)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

[Screenshot of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8YN.png)This is not the exact screen, but the scenario is similar except that this is auto complete list. Any suggestions, as i am unable to interact with the highlighted part.

In appium(1.4.13) with java in win 7, unable to identify the items in a static list/dropdown through UI Automator Viewer. So can we automate the elements which are not identified in this viewer.Tried using the text property, but in vain.

Even tried using appium inspector record option, the issue which i observed here is that the elements behind the list are selected.

Able to automate this scenario in calabash based on text property, with which the properties are found and tried using the classname in appium.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Take a list and add the visible elements in the list. Select the next element one by one from the added list. This will help you in viewing the next item. It will take time but will work fine.

[image]

in this case the suggestion is  displaying from the list.
first get all the suggestions in the list ,then use scrollto() method to find the element in the list view. Then select the element. Hope this works

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i attached a screenshot depicting the scenario. Can u suggest me any other ideas.